# Printing an array of worksheets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The below code attempts to print worksheets across multiple workbooks.

```
Dim wb1, wb2, wb3 as workbook

set wb1 = workbooks.open(......)

set wb2 = workbooks.open(......)

set wb3 = workbooks.open(......)

Sheets(Array(wb1.Sheets(...),wb2.Sheets(...),wb3.Sheets(...))).PrintOut
```

There's a TypeMismatch error in my runs on the last line. What am I Mismatching?

Comment: Looks like you need array with sheet names, not with sheets by itself.

Comment: I attempted to modify the code with wb1.sheets(...).name but it only prints out the last element of the array 'wb3'.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the Office [VBA Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-object-excel), the `Sheets`-Object refers to

> A collection of all the sheets in the specified or active workbook.

Therefore it will not be possible to print sheets from different workbooks together in one print task. Moreover, the syntax ist `Sheets(Index)` so therefore the `index` or the `name` of the sheet has to be passed.

```
Sub testPrint()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Dim s(1) As Worksheet

    Dim mySheet As Variant

    '
    ' collect sheets from different workbooks
    '
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("wm1.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("wm2.xlsm")

    Set s(0) = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set s(1) = wb2.Sheets(1)

    '
    ' print or print preview sheets after each other
    '
    For Each mySheet In s
        mySheet.PrintPreview
    Next

End Sub
```

If You want to print multiple sheets from one workbook in a single print task, You may `select` them and then print all selected ones.